# Codeigniter site login fails after uploading on server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have used codeigniter and flexi_auth for my project. I setup everything on the localhost, and it works pretty well on localhost without any problem. But as soon as I uploaded the database and files on the live server, it won't log me in using admin@admin.com, and password "password123". I don't know it is happening. The same username and password works fine on localhost but fails on live server. It gives me this error message "Your submitted login details are incorrect." Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What do your logs say? Could be permissions, database connectivity issue, all sorts of stuff.

Comment: nothing wrong with database, i registered a new user using "auth/register_account" function. it got registered and logged in successfully. i don't know why my existing users are unable to log in :(

Comment: i saw this fix $config['phpass_hash_portable'] = TRUE;, but this is for tank_auth library. Can you please tell me where to find this in flexi_auth? or something like this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that library.